# Unable to reference dll included in a Nuget Package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, dll-reference

I'm having an weird issue where I am not able to reference a dll included inside a nuget package.

Strange thing is that everyone else that uses this package is able to reference this dll and use classes from it.

Is there a certain setting in my Visual studio which might prevent this??

I'm able to see the dll included as part of this nuget package through solution explorer view...

Thanks in advance!

++ providing more details for the project
We don't have package.config file in the project.
It's a netcoreapp2.1 project

We reference the package through

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.CatalogOrchestrator.EventPublishers.AzureFunctions" Version="1.1.0" />
```

in the .csproj file

dll is reference through the package by below line in the csproj

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\EventPublishers.Common\EventPublishers.Common.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Comment: What kind of project? If using a `packages.config` what does that look like? Otherwise what does the project file look like? (Please update the question.)

Comment: @Richard I provided more information in the question!

Comment: Where is this NuGet package? `Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.CatalogOrchestrator.EventPublishers.AzureFunctions` is not at NuGet.org.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cleaning local nuget cache and reinstalling packages resolved the issue... lol

cleaned local nuget cache through nuget package manager with below command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```